# Using map() to map a button to a Bootstrap 5 grid that spans multiple rows

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I am using the `map()` method to map buttons onto a Bootstrap 5 grid, but I want one of the buttons to span two rows. I know that in Bootstrap the way to do this is to nest two rows in the column that I wish to span two rows, but I'm wondering if this is possible using the map() method? I know that I could not use the map method and type out all the rows, columns and button elements separately, but I would like to know if it is possible using the `map()` method. The difficulty is that `map()` repeats elements, but in this case I would need to essentially insert an extra row.

Here is my code:

```
class ButtonGrid extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
      currentButton: ''
    }
    this.handleClick=this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  buttonGridArr=[
  {
    id: 'clear',
    text: 'C',
    grid: 'col-6 g-0'
  },
  {
    id: 'add',
    text: '+',
    grid: 'col-3 g-0'
  },
  {
    id: 'subtract',
    text: '-',
    grid: 'col-3 g-0'
  },
  {
    id: 'seven',
    text: '7',
    grid: 'col-3 g-0'
  },
  {
    id: 'eight',
    text: '8',
    grid: 'col-3 g-0'
  },
  {
    id: 'nine',
    text: '9',
    grid: 'col-3 g-0'
  },
  {
    id: 'multiply',
    text: 'x',
    grid: 'col-3 g-0'
  },
  {
    id: 'four',
    text: '4',
    grid: 'col-3 g-0'
  },
  {
    id: 'five',
    text: '5',
    grid: 'col-3 g-0'
  },
  {
    id: 'six',
    text: '6',
    grid: 'col-3 g-0'
  },
  {
    id: 'divide',
    text: '÷',
    grid: 'col-3 g-0'
  },
  {
    id: 'one',
    text: '1',
    grid: 'col-3 g-0'
  },
  {
    id: 'two',
    text: '2',
    grid: 'col-3 g-0'
  },
  {
    id: 'three',
    text: '3',
    grid: 'col-3 g-0'
  },
  {
    id: 'equals',
    text: '=',
    grid: 'col-3 g-0'
  },
  {
    id: 'zero',
    text: '0',
    grid: 'col-6 g-0'
  },
  {
    id: 'decimal',
    text: '.',
    grid: 'col-3 g-0'
  }]
  handleClick(event) {
    this.setState(state=>({
      currentButton: event.target.value //Updating state with the button clicked
    }));
    console.log(this.state.currentButton); //Delete
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='container' id='button-grid' style={{borderStyle: 'solid', width: '350px', backgroundColor: 'black'}}>
        <div className='row'> 
        {this.buttonGridArr.map(button=>( //Mapping multiple repeating buttons from an array into a grid
            <div className={button.grid} style={{height: '70px', borderStyle: 'solid', borderWidth: '1px', borderColor: 'black'}}><button type='button' className='btn fw-bold w-100 h-100' key={button.id} id={button.id} value={button.text} style={{color: 'white', borderRadius: '0px'}} onClick={this.handleClick}>{button.text}</button></div>
        ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

It's the equals button that I want to span two rows.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can certainly use map. I see that you're setting a col class to the container div but the button is set with a fixed width of 100px (w-100).  I think this will not spawn multiple rows.

Comment: @AntonioPantano Thanks for the reply. Apologies if I'm not understanding, but if I remove the width of 100% from the buttons, they won't fill the width of their containing divs. I'm not sure I understand how that will help me to make the equals button span two rows?